# jquery ui sotable connected list items container + zinxed issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery ui sortable with connected lists.
I have 2 problems.

**1.Drag Index:** When item dragged from one list say A to other list say B, item goes behind the list B  while dragged but appears correctly once dropped.

**2.Container scrolling:** When item from left side list is dragged to right,instead of showing place holder first, it scrolls container then appear on other list.

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Cd4Sr/

**Similar:** http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-splitselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-splitselect-selected" style="width: 50%;">
        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
        </div>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="ui-splitselect-list" style="height: 200px;">
            <li class="ui-splitselect-item ui-state-default">
                <a class='ui-splitselect-handle-drag'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></a>
                <span class="ui-splitselect-handle-select">Test1</span>
                <a class="ui-splitselect-handle-move" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-splitselect-available" style="width:49.8%;">
        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
        </div>
        <ul id="sortable2" class="ui-splitselect-list" style="height: 200px;">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-splitselect{font-size:.8em;width:100%!important;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect ul{-moz-user-select:none}
.ui-splitselect .ui-widget-header{border:none;font-size:11px}
.ui-splitselect-selected{float:left;border:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-available{float:left;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-list{position:relative;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;list-style:none;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-item{cursor:default;line-height:20px;height:20px;font-size:11px;list-style:none;display:list-item;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;margin:1px;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-item.ui-sortable-helper{z-index:99999}
.ui-splitselect-handle-select{float:left}
.ui-splitselect-handle-drag{float:left;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;cursor:pointer;margin:0 10px 0 5px;padding:2px 5px}
.ui-splitselect-handle-move{text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;float:right;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;margin:0 5px 0 10px;padding:2px 5px}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `overflow: auto;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`  from the class `ui-splitselect-list`.  Set the class `ui-splitselect` overflow to `overflow-y: auto;`.

Here is the updated [>>>JSFiddle<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd4Sr/1/)

CSS:

```
 .ui-splitselect {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width:100% !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-y: auto;    /*-----updated-----*/
}
.ui-splitselect-list {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /*-----updated  Removed overflow: auto;-----*/
    /*-----updated  Removed overflow-x: hidden;-----*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
     connectWith: ".ui-splitselect-list",
     containment: ".ui-splitselect",
     scroll: false,
     placeholder: "ui-state-highlight ui-splitselect-item"
 }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: UPDATE: If I darg the items to right, same container problem occurs.For Both lists.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem.

Comment: The functionality appears to be correct.  Upon dragging the yellow place holder moves from current position to new position in opposing element.  The dragged item is also displaying over the containing elements.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try Dragging an item to bottom, Container div breaks,
Try Dragging an item from right list to further right, scrolling of container div occurs.

Comment: I need Scroll to appear only for Y-direction if there are more list items. No scrolling should occur in X-direction while dragging.In your case if I drag items far too right, scroll bar for X-dir appears.Also when I move item too far in bottom it breaks Container Div Border.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  I am testing now.

Comment: Ok. Got It. I added  ```containment: ".ui-splitselect",``` to your solution and now it is working fine for me. Kindly test So i can have other opinion. http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Cd4Sr/2/

Comment: The containment coupled with "scroll: false," is the solution>  Here is updated JSFiddle, I added more elements for you see the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/Cd4Sr/5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40251/discussion-between-django-and-spencer-leonard)