# jQuery UI Sortable connected list css issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery ui sortable with connected lists. I have 2 problems with one most important requirement.

1. Items goes behind the other list while dragging `li.ui-splitselect-item`
2. Dragging item to right(when mouse is too right) creates Horizontal scroll

**IMPORTANT:**  Lists `ul.ui-splitselect-list` should have `overflow-y:auto;` So Header of lists stay fixed
   and only list items are scrolled
 [image]

**NOTE:**
I previous asked this question on [STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674409/jquery-ui-sotable-connected-list-items-container-zinxed-issue) but didnt notice my important requirement was missing from solution so i opened question again with clarity.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/z67Td/

**HTML Mockup:**

```
<div class="ui-splitselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="height:200px;" >
    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-splitselect-selected">
        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
             List1
        </div>
        <ul id="sortable1"  class="ui-splitselect-list" style="height: 332px;">
            <li class="ui-splitselect-item ui-state-default">
                <a class='ui-splitselect-handle-drag'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></a>
                <span class="ui-splitselect-handle-select">TEST-List1</span>
                <a class="ui-splitselect-handle-move" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-splitselect-available"  >
        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
              List2
        </div>
        <ul id="sortable2"  class="ui-splitselect-list" style="height: 332px;">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-splitselect{font-size:.8em;width:100%!important;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect ul{-moz-user-select:none}
.ui-splitselect .ui-widget-header{border:none;font-size:11px}
.ui-splitselect-selected{height:100%!important;float:left;border:none;width:50%;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-available{height:100%!important;width:49.4%;float:left;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-list{height:92%!important;position:relative;list-style:none;overflow:auto;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-item{cursor:default;line-height:20px;height:20px;font-size:11px;list-style:none;display:list-item;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;margin:1px;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect-item.ui-sortable-helper{z-index:99999}
.ui-splitselect-handle-select{float:left}
.ui-splitselect-handle-drag{float:left;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;cursor:pointer;margin:0 10px 0 5px;padding:2px 5px}
.ui-splitselect-handle-move{text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;float:right;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;margin:0 5px 0 10px;padding:2px 5px}
```

**JS:**

```
 $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
     connectWith: ".ui-splitselect-list",
     containment: ".ui-splitselect",
     scroll: false,
     placeholder: "ui-state-highlight ui-splitselect-item"
 }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `appendTo: document.body` and `helper: clone` options for `sortable`, like this:

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  appendTo: document.body,
  helper: "clone",
  connectWith: ".ui-splitselect-list",
  containment: ".ui-splitselect",
  scroll: false,
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight ui-splitselect-item"
}).disableSelection();
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XpP25/2/

Trick is in creating sorting helper that clones your original element, and then appending it to body element to resolve `zIndex` issues. All helpers are automatically removed after stop event of draggable and sortable, so it shouldn't mess your code :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i drag element in ur JSFIDDLE, it seems to loose font-style. how can i fix that
 Thankx

Comment: I think it's something with original jquery ui css. Clone always have ui-draggable and ui-draggable-dragging classes, but to be honest I don't recognise anything other than cursor that's connected with this classes in css. Sorry. I'll try to find solution!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with nested sortable items. I have multiple sortable containers, that make up a grid, then widgets inside of those sortable containers. Inside of each widget there is a nested sortable container which takes up the width and height. Inside of the nested sortables I can have multiple nested-widgets, spanning the width of the nested sortable.

Here is how one of those sortables would look:

```
<div class="sortable">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="nested-sortable">
      <div class="nested-widget"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, once I started dragging my nested sortable item, it would go behind every outer widget except for the one containing it. I tried changing the z-index of the items on sort start and no luck. I needed something like jQuery UI's Draggable `stack` option, which "stacks" the currently dragged item over all other items of the same class.

Here is jQuery UI's draggable stack function on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/f71f4abfe59dd423018073b2104047d89f5aadd6/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L800) at line 800.

So, my friend and I modified that code a bit, and called it on the "outer" widget.

```
$.fn.stack = function () {
    // where $(this) == '.widget'
    var o = $(this).closest('.sortable').siblings('.sortable').find('.widget');

    // create an array of all the widgets
    var group = $(o).sort(function(a,b) {
        // compare the each set of widgets
        return (parseInt($(a).css("z-index"),10) || 1) - (parseInt($(b).css("z-index"),10) || 1);
    });
    if (!group.length) { return; }

    var min = parseInt($(group[0]).css('z-index')) || 1; // first widget's z-index
    $(group).each(function(i) {
        // increase each widget's z-index by min + $(this) widget's index value
        $(this).css('z-index',  min + i);
    });

    // make currently dragged widget's z-index min + length of group
    $(this[0]).css('z-index', min + group.length);
}
```

Then call in sortable start:

```
$('.nested-sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).closest('.widget').stack();
    }
});
```

Here is my codepen for reference: [Nested Grid System](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/zYYZrLz)